# AsyncImage shadow when displaying a png

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have an issue with the AsyncImage composable , when I have setup a shadow and attempt to load a png with transparent background .

This is how I have my AsyncImage setup for shadows .

```
  AsyncImage(
  model = selectedImage,
  fallback = ColorPainter(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary),
  contentDescription = "avatar",
  contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,            // crop the image if it's not a square
  modifier = Modifier
    .shadow(10.dp, CircleShape)
    .size(imageSize.size)
    .clip(CircleShape)                       // clip to the circle shape
    .border(2.dp, LocalContentColor.current, CircleShape)   // add a border (optional)
)
```

As you can see [image] , when no URL is loaded in the selectedImage property , the drop shadow appears fine .

However when an image is loaded , we can see some artifact behind the actual image. It appears as if the shadow is attempted on the actual image inside the AsyncImage composable .
Even though the intention is to attach a shadow on the entire composable , not the image inside.

Any ideas?

Also note there is no effect when i reorder the shadow call into the modifier chain

Comment: All the logos doing it or just the Microsoft one

Comment: all the logos which have transparency :/ . i . e. pngs

Comment: now any solution?